# finite size scaling and collapsing of data of different system sizes into a single curve

Tags: plot, curve-fitting, curve, data-fitting

I have a set of data (x_arr, y_arr) for 3 different system sizes. I want to plot this                                        data (y_arr for three different system sizes) with respect to a function defined like: $L^\alpha f(x_arr/L^\beta)$, where alpha, beta and function f are chosen such that all the data(for different system sizes) collpases onto a single curve. I tried to do curve fitting for three different system sizes by taking 'f' as a polynomial function of degree 7 but don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is necessary to know the function $f$ with which you want to fit the data of your curves for different sizes $L$.
In the practice of finite size scaling, which is often used in critical point analysis, what is done is fitting the curves for different sizes and plotting the observable (usually an order parameter) as a function of the argument $(x-xc)L^a$.
The fit function $f$ depends on the shape of your data; for example, a seventh-degree polynomial might be a bit too complicated as it would require many fit parameters.
A good idea might be to start with a function like this:

$$f(x, L) = f_0 + f_1((x-x_c)L^a)$$.

In this way, your fit parameters are $f_0$, $f_1$, $x_c$, and $a$.
For instance, if you are familiar with gnuplot, you should organize your data in any file (*.txt, *.dat) so that it is structured like this:

```
# First size
# x_arr         L           y_arr
x_1             L_1         y_1
x_2             L_1         y_2
.               .           .
.               .           .
x_n             L_1         y_n

# Second size
# x_arr         L           y_arr
x_1             L_2         y_1
x_2             L_2         y_2
.               .           .
.               .           .
x_n             L_2         y_n

# Third size
# x_arr         L           y_arr
x_1             L_3         y_1
x_2             L_3         y_2
.               .           .
.               .           .
x_n             L_3         y_n
```

let us call this file 'data.dat'.

In gnuplot:

```
$ f(x, L) = f0 + f1*(x-xc)*L**a

$ fit f(x, L) 'data.dat' u 1:2:3 via f0, f1, xc, a
```

The output of the fit will be `f0`, `f1`, `xc`, `a` with their respective errors (note that we are only interested in `xc` and `a`).

Once you get the fit parameters you can easily plot your observable as a function of $(x-x_c)L^a$. If the fit is done properly, you should see a good collapse onto a single curve. If this doesn't happen, try to increase the degree of the polynomial, e.g., $f(x, y) = (f_0 + f_1((x-x_c)y^a) + f_2((x-x_c)y^a)^2).